# Reactjs select - getting the input select onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the `this` element of the select box on change.
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

```
<Select
   name="propertytype"
   value={this.state.propertytype}
   options={optionsPropertyType}
   onChange={this.handlePropertyTypeChange}
   placeholder="Property Type"
/>
```

I have tried to get the `this` element that invoked the handler. But the `onChange` function just retrieves the `value` and `label` of the select box.

```
handlePropertyTypeChange: function(val) {
    console.log("this -property change", this);
    console.log("val", val);
    this.setState({propertytypename: val.label});
    this.setState({propertytype: val.value});
  },
```

Comment: What do `console.log("this -property change", this)` and `console.log("val", val)` output?

Comment: Do you need the `event`?

Comment: The `this` element here is your react class not the `react-select` element

Comment: Yeah I need the event - so I can reveal the label above the select box that has changed. Its a style requirement. - and yes that is the problem the this element I've found doesn't appear to contain the touched select box

Comment: I need to do something like this to show a label above the select box --- $(element).parent().find("label").css("visibility", "visible");

Comment: Is the label rendered by the `Select` component or your own `<label>` HTML?

Comment: Own label. I've "fixed" this bug by looking for the hidden input that matches the value. After a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

Better way to use this type of handlers is to use bind(this).

```
onChange={this.handlePropertyTypeChange.bind(this)}
```

so this will be your component

or if you want to access target element you can use react refs or event.target